# when to hash a passwrd?

Tags: hash, passwords

In my program I get the password into a variable (eg:string) and then before storing it into the database I hash it.Is that the correct and secured method?

Or should I hash it before storing it into a variable i.e. as soon as the user type in the password should it be hashed?

Answer (score 0):

@Erina
Think about the purpose of hashing.

If someone breaks into your database they will not find passwords but only hashes which need to be brute forced into passwords in order to be useful.

By allowing the client to send a hash instead of the password you effectively make the hash the new password and all benefits are lost. i.e. if someone gets into the database they can instantly log into all accounts with the data they find there.

Therefore the client should always send the password and the server should do 
the hashing.

Comment: <input type="password" encrypt="sha1" pattern=".{6,}">    Is this valid?

Comment: @Erina:
You can check here. Hope it will be helpful.
https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2016/11/password-hashing-in-the-browser/

Comment: Thank you. I did stumble upon that website.But it did not work!